# Is there any way where we can calculate parameter covariance matrix instead of correlation matrix in python lmfit package

Tags: python, variance, lmfit, parameterization, covariance-matrix

I have re-parameterize Arrhenius equation of form  **k = kref*exp(-E/R((1/T)-(1/Tref))** and i wanted to estimate the values of parameters E & kref which i got from lmfit package and correlations between it too.
However the whole idea of re-parameterization was to see if we are getting low correlation between k0 and E after re-parameterization of original Arrhenius equation i.e. **k = ko*exp(-E/RT)** where **kref = ko*exp(-E/RTref)** so to do that i got following relation

```
                     Cov(ko,E)/k0  = Var(E)/RTref  -  Cov(Kref,E)/kref
```

So my question is that is there any way we can find Var(E) and also standard deviation of kref??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand what you are asking - your notation is not clear.  It is really always better to provide a minimal and complete example of working code.

The fit result from lmfit does include the covariance matrix (`covar`) between the variable parameters.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks M Newville for the quick response. Well I'm just looking for a way to print covariance matrix instead of correlation matrix in report_fit.

Comment: It might seem obvious, but if you have a question, then ask that question, and don't ask a different question.  You did not ask "how do I print the covariance matrix?". If you had asked that, the answer would be easy:  print the `covar` attribute of the `MinimizerResult` or `ModelResult` value returned by your fit.  If you need more help than that then, really no kidding, provide a minimal and complete example.